Error while running the command 'anchor build' - '`-Znext-lockfile-bump'
I am following the solana bootcamp on youtube. When I build my anchor for the first time, it shows the following error:
anchor build
error: failed to parse lock file at: /home/sarthak/solana/P2-Voting-App/voting-dapp/anchor/Cargo.lock
Caused by:
lock file version 4 requires -Znext-lockfile-bump
Versions I am using for the project:

Solana - 2.0.20
anchor - 0.30.1
avm - 0.30.1
rustc - rustc 1.84.0-nightly (a0d98ff0e 2024-10-31)

I am a beginner in solana development. Can someone help me with the error.

Change version 4 to 3 in your cargo.lock file


It is already version 4.
I also tried to downgrade the solana version to 1.18.18 that is used in bootcamp but still I am getting the same error.
Caused by:
lock file version 4 requires -Znext-lockfile-bump

Sorry, please change from 4 to 3.

Nice, this solved my issue as well!

i did this - Please change cargo version from 4 to 3 in cargo.lock file –
but get these errors:
error: custom attribute panicked
--> programs/spl/src/lib.rs:12:1
|
12 | #[program]
| ^^^^^^^^^^
error: could not compile spl (lib test) due to 1 previous error; 3 warnings emitted
Error: Building IDL failed
below is my setup:
(base) $ rustc --version
rustc 1.83.0 (90b35a623 2024-11-26)
(base) $ anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.30.0
(base) $ solana --version
solana-cli 1.18.14 (src:d8e08244; feat:4215500110, client:SolanaLabs)
(base) $ cargo --version
cargo 1.83.0 (5ffbef321 2024-10-29)

While installing the dependencies, ensure that cargo version matches the Rust version.
The current version that worked for me are:
Solana - 1.18.18
rustc - 1.79.0 (129f3b996 2024-06-10)
cargo - 1.79.0 (ffa9cf99a 2024-06-03)
anchor-cli 0.30.1

Please change cargo version from 4 to 3 in cargo.lock file
